# Error while executing Postman Test Script

Tags: testing, postman, postman-testcase

I am writing the Postman test cases. I am getting an error from following test-case

```
pm.test("Response to have expected data", function () {
   pm.expect(documentIdArray).to.have.members(['5868', '4', '5874']);  
});

There was an error in evaluating the test script:  Error: expected [ '4837', '4', '5874' ] to have the same members as [ '5868', '4', '5874' ]
```

Comment: What is the value of `documentIdArray ` and how is that getting set? You're missing half of the information here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having string in documentIdArray. You can parse it:

```
pm.test("Response to have expected data", function () {
   pm.expect(JSON.parse(documentIdArray)).to.have.members(['5868', '4', '5874']);  
});
```

Else  stringify the array and compare ( Recommended ) as the end point is not actually returning array but string it should be a bug

```
pm.test("Response to have expected data", function () {
   pm.expect(documentIdArray).to.be.equal(JSON.stringify(['5868', '4', '5874']));  
});
```